# Change Library Name in Solution Explorer and Folder in Visual Studio

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2017

I changed the name of a Library in VS 2017 (vb project) and then changed the Folder to match and it removed all of the libraries content ... where is the path being referenced in the solution to where I can correct the path?

Seems like a simple correction, however, I checked the applicationhost.config and seem to be missing something

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I just had to rebuild the library lol ... simple answer, as it always seems to be lol